# Compiling code in C in Code::Blocks gives an error: cannot find -lbgi

Tags: c, codeblocks, bgi

Using C. Need to use graphics library for my uni lab, but when I try to compile the code in Code::Blocks, I'd always get this error: ld.exe cannot find -lbgi. I added  graphics.h and winbgim.h files into include folder of Code::Blocks directory and added libbgi.a file in the lib folder of Code:Blocks. Then added link libraries through Settigs > Compiler > Global compiler setting > Linker Settings, in Link Libraries added the path to the libbgi.a file, and added the following to the Other Linker Settings: -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32. Have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `bgi`? It is like 30 years old.

Comment: @EugeneSh. sadly, my prof doesn't care